# How to plot normal distribution with mean 10 and standard deviation 2?

Tags: plotting, distributions

My code is `Plot[Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[10, 2], x], {x, 0, 20}]]`, but it just produces a blank plot. Why is this?

Comment: Try without the `Table[...]` bit.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: .. or change `Plot` to `ListLinePlot`

Comment: It says "Binary file loading of package Statistics`ContinuousDistributions`NormalDistributions`  by \
symbol NormalDistribution failed. >"

Comment: `s=2;m=10;Plot[1/Sqrt[2 Pi s^2]E^-((x-m)^2/(2 s^2)),{x,5,15}]`

Comment: To amplify upon comment by @b.gatessucks `Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[10, 2], x], {x, 0, 20}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
      ListLinePlot[Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[10, 2], x], {x, 0, 20}], 
       PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 15]]
```

[image: plot]